# lambda function does not update the reference array

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I have a method which basically updates each value of the passed reference array by 5.

Initially I tried the below options but it wouldn't update the reference array.

Option 1:

```
void Int_Array_Update(std::vector<int>& param)
{   
    auto f1 = [](int n) { return n + 5; };
    std::for_each(param.begin(), param.end(), f1);
}
```

Option 2:

```
void Int_Array_Update(std::vector<int>& param)
{   
    auto f1 = [&](int n) { return n + 5; };
    std::for_each(param.begin(), param.end(), f1);
}
```

Option 3:

```
void Int_Array_Update(std::vector<int>& param)
{   
    auto f1 = [&param](int n) { return n + 5; };
    std::for_each(param.begin(), param.end(), f1);
}
```

The workaround I have currently is as below:

```
void Int_Array_Update(std::vector<int>& param)
{   
    for (int i = 0; i < param.size(); ++i)
        param[i] = param[i] + 5;
}
```

I am not able to find any answers why the lambda function is not updating the reference vector or maybe I am doing something wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std:.for_each` does not update the elements in the range the way you expect. `std::for_each` applies the lambda to each element, but does not care about the return value from the lambda.

You want `std::transform` for that:

```
std::transform(param.begin(), param.end(), param.begin(), f1);
//                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                                              |
//                it starts writing the result here
```

To work with `std::for_each` you would need to receive the argument *by-reference* in the lambda and make the update to the argument directly instead of returning it:

```
auto f1 = [](int& n) { n += 5; }; // int& and add to n directly
std::for_each(param.begin(), param.end(), f1);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ted. Now it all makes sense :)